# Происхождение фразы "ты весь в белом" и ее аналоги

Tags: этимология, фраза, идиомы

Я пишу рассказ, и в одном месте персонаж произносит фразу "Я был не прав, но и ты не весь в белом" в ответ на некие претензии.

В моей голове, эта фраза имеет оттенок "ты тоже не с чистыми руками вышел из ситуации", "и твоя вина в этом есть", что-то в таком ключе, хотя основной смысл — "ты тоже не безгрешен". Однако же, у меня есть сомнения в том, общепринято ли именно такое восприятие.

Кроме того, действие происходит в другой стране (предполагается что на самом деле герои разговаривают на другом языке. Поэтому мне хотелось бы, чтобы фраза была кросс-культурной или хотя бы переводимой. То есть я не хочу использовать локализм не имеющий аналогов в других странах.

Соответственно вопрос: откуда эта фраза вообще появилась и какие есть более кросс-культурные или хотя бы переводимые аналоги.

Ближайшее, что приходит мне в голову — "а кто не без греха" или "ты тоже не безгрешен", но мне хотелось бы избежать отсылок к библии (если это возможно). К тому же, вариант "ты тоже не безгрешен" кажется мне менее резким, что тоже не вполне меня устраивает.

Заранее спасибо за помощь, и надеюсь, что я обращаюсь по адресу.

Comment: Are you writing your story in Russian? If yes, what's wrong with the Russian phrase you mentioned? If no, then this is off-topic.

Comment: Yes, I'm writing in Russian, but it is supposed that characters actually speak another language (and they are not from Russia, etc.), so I'd like not to use a phrase that could be understand only by Russians. That's why I think that some cross-cultural phrase with same meaning would be better.

Comment: well you still put Russian words in their mouths, right? I believe phrases like *чёрный день* or *белоручка* can be used when conveying speech of people from a strange land, even though they might not see black as a color of grief and their hands might not be white when clean. Could you please provide some context?

Comment: Yes, I put Russian words in their mouths. And I don't want to argue on whether it should be translatable or cross-cultural. Let's say, I just want it this way. And yes, I will edit the question so that my concern is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В английском есть похожее: Knight in shining armor.

Поэтому, кажется, можно считать эту фразу переводимой.

Comment: Судя по тому, что я нашла, Knight in shining armor — это совсем не то... ( http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-knight-in-shining-armour ).

Comment: @Alissa в современном языке обе фразы обычно используются в ироническом ключе и с близким смыслом.

Answer (score 5):

В России есть довольно старый и многим известный анекдот, из которого, скорее всего, и взята фраза "и тут выхожу *я -- весь в белом*": Пришёл в цирк человек с проектом нового номера. «Поднимают под купол здоровенный брезентовый мешок. Шпрехшталмейстер в него стреляет. Мешок лопается. И оказывается — он заполнен дерьмом. Шпрехшталмейстер в дерьме. Униформисты в дерьме. Оркестр в дерьме. Публика вся в дерьме. И тут выхожу я — весь в белом».

Рассказывают этот анекдот по-разному. Вот другой вариант: Приходит мужик к директору цирка и говорит: "У меня есть для вашего шоу замечательный номер". Директор: "Ну давай, излагай." Мужик с блеском в глазу: "Подвешиваем под потолок огроменную бадью с дерьмом. Гаснет свет, только прожектора шур-шур, маэстро взмахнул палочкой, зарокотал барабан, всё громче и громче, и вдруг эта бадья из-под самого купола шмяк... Весь цирк в дерьме, и тут выхожу Я. Весь в белом."

Comment: В том то и проблема, что, по всей видимости, анекдот сей известен только в России

Comment: @Alissa А на какую аудиторию вы рассчитываете? На каком языке рассказ?

Comment: Рассказ на русском. Но соль не в аудитории, а в правдоподобности.

Comment: Все носители русского языка эту фразу поймут. Я не вижу здесь проблемы.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин , понять-то поймут, но это как если бы в рассказе о руси 13го века готовили картошку. Вроде бы ничего такого, все поймут. Вот только в Россию картошка была завезена гораздо позже. Мой случай менее критичен, но я стараюсь такого рода несоответствий избегать.

Answer (score 3):

Если в этом месте не предполагается обязательного наличия какого-нибудь фразеологизма, то можно сказать просто:

> Я был не прав, но и ты ничем не лучше
>   Я был не прав, но и ты хорош

Из "универсальных" оборотов на ум приходит только ангел:

> Но и ты - не ангел

Comment: Это конечно вариант. Но стилистически бедновато получается...

Comment: Вариант с ангелом мне нравится. Спасибо.